# git log after(contains) commit? (with --graph)

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-log

I knew that

- `git branch --contains <REVISION>` can show names of all child branches since `<REVISION>`
- `git log --branches=<BRANCH_REGEX>` can filter branches

Is there any way to conceptually direct output of the former command to the latter?
i.e. **`git branch --contains <REVISION> | git log --branches=`**

The goal is to filter branches when using `git log --decorate --graph --oneline [OTHER_OPTIONS]`

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to conceptually direct output of [one] command [as arguments to another]?

The shell (`sh` or `bash` or whatever shell command interpreter you use) generally has a method of doing that.

There are two common spellings, one using backquotes which is convenient for very short items, and one using `$(...)` which is better in general because it nests properly.

The problem with `git branch --contains` is that it formats its output improperly: it will print `*` if one of the branch names that it prints, that contains the given commit, is the current branch.  You must either do something to remove the asterisk, or use a more command-oriented command.  The latter is better in general but requires that your Git not be too old (2.6 or later): replace `git branch --contains <rev>` with `git for-each-ref --contains=<rev> --format='%(refname)' ref/heads`.

Now, you can't turn this into a set of glob patterns for `--branches=` for `git log`, but you don't *need* to, because all `--branches=<glob>` does is tell `git log` to start from the references that match `refs/heads/<glob>`, and the `git for-each-ref` is already going to produce a complete list of such references.  So all you need to do is pass that complete list of references on to `git log`.

Since shells also expand `$name` as a variable holding some name, I'll use that below instead of `<...>`, which is otherwise ambiguous (it could mean a literal less-than sign etc).  This gives:

```
git log $log_args $(git for-each-ref --contains=$rev --format='%(refname)')
```

If your `git for-each-ref` is too old to handle `--contains`, you must use `git branch --contains` and strip off the first two columns, e.g.:

```
git log $log_args $(git branch --contains $rev | cut -c3-)
```

This has a flaw because `git branch` does not prefix the branch names with `refs/heads`.  If you have a branch named `xyzzy` *and* a tag *also* named `xyzzy`, `git branch` knows to use the *branch* name, and `--branches=xyzzy` would know to use the *branch* rather than the *tag*, but just naming `xyzzy` on the command line will get you the tag, because in general tags have higher priority than branches.  (See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), which lists the six steps taken to resolve a name: *try it as a tag* is step 3 and *try it as a branch* is step 4.  The tag has higher priority.)  To fix that—to avoid [this xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/data_pipeline.png)—you need to fancy it up some more:

```
git log $log_args $(git branch --contains $rev | cut -c3- | sed s,^,refs/heads,)
```

for instance.  (And of course, see also [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1597/).)

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
And I add the following in global .gitconfig and put it in [alias] tag to simplify routine typing.
`loggc = "!git logg $(git for-each-ref --contains=${1:-HEAD} --format='%(refname)')" # [Usage] git loggc [<REVISION>]`
 where `logg` is also a predefined alias